# How to dynamically resize buttons in a stack view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I have a UI designed like this:

[image]

and the buttons are in a stack view. Each button has a height constraint. I want to be able to programmatically remove buttons from the view but when that happens, have the rest of the buttons increase their height so there isn't a huge gap between them. Problem shown here:
[image]

What constraints/layouts do I need to add/remove to achieve what I want? Thanks!

Comment: Don't set height constraints on your buttons. Set a height constraint on the Stack View, and let *it* size the buttons.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks, I just tried that and it made my buttons' heights really short. I want to minimize the gaps between the buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two views of the *exact same* `UIStackView` with the *exact same* settings. The only difference is one button was deleted.

[image]

and the settings:

[image]

The ***only*** element with constraints is the Stack View - set to 300 x 500, centered X and Y

Comment: Ah, I was missing the Fill Equally setting. Thanks! This worked.